# Why Delete link doesn't work in this Ruby on Rails project?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am practicing this RoR tutorial project of Michael Hartl: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book

I am using Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3.1 on Ubuntu 11.04 with Apache and MySQL.

I am here now: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/updating-showing-and-deleting-users#sec:destroying_users (where I have s list of users and a Delete link for each of them, me being the admin).

This is the delete link which supposed to work:

```
<%= link_to "delete", user, :method => :delete, :confirm => "You sure?",
                            :title => "Delete #{user.name}" %>
```

But when I mouseover I see this: "localhost/users/2" (for example)
And when I click on the Delete link it directs me to the user's profile. I don't get any confirmation window and no action is done (delete). It's like a link to their profile and nothing else.
I am using Chrome but in Firefox is the same.

This is what I have:

1)the gem "jquery-rails" is installed

2)applications.js (from app/assets/javascripts) has these lines:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

3)application.html.erb (from app/views/layouts) has these lines:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

In view source I see:

```
  <script src="/assets/defaults.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
  <meta content="njPO91rB7p3EtTblD4jf4rkCVt+M76SKUt0rQhHc+qY=" name="csrf-token" />
```

4)in users_controllers.rb (from app/controllers) I have:

```
 before_filter :authenticate, :only => [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]
 before_filter :correct_user, :only => [:edit, :update]
 before_filter :admin_user,   :only => :destroy

 def destroy
  User.find(params[:id]).destroy
  flash[:success] = "User destroyed."
  redirect_to users_path
 end

 private
  def admin_user
    redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user.admin?
  end
```

5)in routes.rb (from config) I have:

```
resources :users
```

What is wrong with that Delete link?
I've searched StackOverflow for answers but apparently I couldn't find one to suit my situation.

On the same RoR project the follow/unfollow button using Ajax works just fine (can't post a second link here for now because I just registered to the SO).

So, why the link doesn't work? Is it a Javascript problem or some other problem which I am not seeing?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe @mhartl http://stackoverflow.com/users/57750/mhartl can answer to this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try using

```
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

instead of :defaults

Comment: This would be right. :defaults is a hangover from < 3.1 days.

Comment: This is why Chapter 1 has the line (as of this writing) "gem install --version 3.0.11". Using any other version of Rails will lead to incompatibilities. (Note: The Rails 3.1 edition is in preparation.)

Answer (score 5):

try switching it to button_to "delete" instead of link_to "delete"  That worked for me when nothing else would

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `resources :users` in your routes.rb file. That should give you the basic CRUD routing.

Comment: Yes, I have these in routes.rb: 
resources :users
resources :sessions, :only => [:new, :create, :destroy]

Answer (score 0):

In my current Rails 3.1 projects I use

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', rest_datatype, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %>
```

Comment: I get this error: undefined local variable or method `rest_datatype'

Comment: that's Benjamin's model.  Yours is user

Comment: Well, this "<%= link_to 'Destroy', user, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %>" doesn't work either. I get the same situation (going to the profile and nothing happens in between).

Answer (score 0):

I've faced this recently. Try to look in the

```
config/application.rb:
```

Let's see if there is a string

```
Rails.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
```

Because of this, js libraries are not compiled or loaded. Therefore, method `method:: delete` didn't work. Try to delete this.